# No launch/menu bar. Can only open terminal

Tags: menu

I logged into Ubuntu and my menu bar and launch bar are gone.

I cannot use Ubuntu as there as the only this I see is my wallpaper. I have restarted and it has not done anything.

I can open the terminal, and I can run commands, but that is all I can do.

[Here is a picture of my screen with the terminal open (sorry for the bad quality.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvqUx.jpg)

As you can see I don't even have the ability to close, maximise or minimise windows (I can close by using alt+f4 though.)

I have tried various command like alt+f2 and other commands, but these don't appear to work.

Is there a way in the terminal to open the home folder as a window? If I can have a folder open, then I can at least use Ubuntu to an extent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you type `unity --replace` in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `unity --reset` or `unity --replace` in the terminal. Just log-out or shut-down and hopefully you should see all the Unity features (Launcher etc.)

I've never seen this happen before. It's quite werid.

Hope this helps!

P.S. You could report this as a bug.

Comment: `unity --{reset,replace}` would only resolve the problem temporarily and I'm sure the OP is looking for a long-term solution. Also, before reporting a bug, it'd be better to check what has gone wrong. Maybe the OP has removed some core packages or has edited some important configuration (and these two are common cases that happen frequently).